# Re-using rails db :id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Can I re-use a rails database record's :id if that record is deleted?

For instance, if I have 5 records with id's 1-5 and I delete items 2 and 4 from the database, will ActiveRecord use those id's again? If so, is that automatic, or do you need to tell ActiveRecord to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID generation is typically the function of the database you are using.

SQL based databases are not able to be configured to reuse id's like this, as it would incur a huge performance penalty.

ActiveRecord doesn't have any configuration to perform this type of behavior, you would need to implement a custom query to find the lowest id that doesn't exist, or have some other method of managing freed IDs.

It depends on your needs, but it is usually easiest to never reuse id's.